# Bootstrap modal open and close only one time then it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[image]

When i run following command in chrome console

```js
$("#inactive-selected-requests-modal").modal("show")
```

it does not display modal and overlay comes there. the chrome console output is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="inactive-selected-requests-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with below function,  i was deleting the modal html instead of modal body

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#inactive-selected-requests-modal", function () {
            $("#inactive-selected-requests-modal").html("");
        });
```

To correct i change above function line to:

```
$("#inactive-selected-requests-modal-body").html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `style="display: none;"`. It has solved the problem for me.